# Caret error says: "Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models", but I'm passing it continuous data

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I'm trying to pass **caret** some training data where *y* is an n x 1 matrix of continuous data. Calling `typeof(dfm_y1_train)` confirms that it is of type *double*.

This is the code I'm using:

```r
ctrl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 20,
  repeats = 3,
  allowParallel = TRUE,
  search = "random",
  verbose = TRUE
)

rf_base <- train(
  x = dfm_X1_train,
  y = dfm_y1_train,
  method = "rf",
  # tuneGrid = tune_grid,
  tuneLength = 20,
  trControl = ctrl,
  num.trees = 1000
)
```

How I can encourage / convince / force **caret** to apply regression using a Random Forest?

I also tried using `method = "ranger"` from [Random Forest Regression using Caret](https://gist.github.com/rfarouni/9be5c651af60d5d7cc6c9b529e821b47), but had the same issue.

[**Edit**] As requested, some more details and data.

**dfm_X1_train**:

*Note*: I anonymised the column names. `t_x` are uni-grams generated from in "documents".

```
Document-feature matrix of: 90,264 documents, 2,144 features (99.74% sparse) and 3 docvars.
        features
docs      t_1 t_2    t_3 t_4  t_5     t_6   t_7     t_7 t_8 t_9
  112784    0   0      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
  312095    0   0      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
  217494    0   0      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
  225811    0   0      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
  342907    0   0      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
  359949    1   1      0   0    0       0     0       0   0   0
[ reached max_ndoc ... 90,258 more documents, reached max_nfeat ... 2,134 more features ]
```

**dfm_y1_train**

```
A matrix: 6 × 1 of type dbl
log_price
1.50851199
3.66356165
3.13331794
2.56494936
-0.01005034
2.99573227
```

Comment: Is it possible that you share the first six rows of your data, x and y? We can help you better with some sample data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @Alexis, MrFlick: hope this helps?

Comment: if you read the help page, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train, y should be a vector, so in your case, if you do `dfm_y1_train = as.numeric(dfm_y1_train)` it should work

Comment: It should be *me* with the word stupid before my username... thanks heaps!